# How to create environment in python without anaconda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

Is there any way of creating virtual environment in python without using Anaconda ?

Comment: Yes. Searching the web for _"python virtual environment"_ is a good start. I would not recommend anything more here, because that is strictly off topic.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to do that using Docker containers.  Here's a brief example.

First, you need Docker up and running in your machine:

https://www.docker.com/get-started/

Create a Dockerfile with the following lines:

```
FROM Ubuntu

# In the following line replace python with the specific version required
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install python

# Use the following lines to install the required packages
RUN pip install pandas
RUN pip install numpy
```

Then, build your image using the following lines on the terminal running in the same folder where you saved the Dockerfile:

```
docker build Dockerfile -t yourname/yourimagename
```

Finally, run it:

```
docker run -it yourname/yourimagename bash
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You could simply resort to the [virtualenv](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/) pip package which offers the ability to create and activate multiple python environments without having to rely on anaconda.

Answer (score -3):

If you do not need to manage multiple environments for different projects you can install python packages through pip.You can find the list of available packages from Python Package Index (PyPI)https://pypi.python.org/pypi.You already have pip, if you are using Python 2 >= 2.7.9 or Python 3 >= 3.4. Otherwise you need toinstall pip, following the instructions at https://packaging.python.org/installing/#requirements-for-installing-packages). In a terminal,

you enter the following to install a package.

pip search pip
install --user

Comment: I think based on the question they want to manage multiple environments.. without anaconda